# Can we determine the numeric sign of proportional constant using dimensional analysis?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

is it true or false
can we determine the numeric sign of proportional constants in a physical equation using dimensional analysis?

Comment: Numeric sign? You mean like $E(r)=-V(r)/r$, where $E(r)$ is electric field. You are referring "$-$" sign?

Comment: Intuitively I'd say dimensional analysis does not give you more information on the sign than the original equation.

Comment: Yes the numeric sign(+,-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false.  Numerical analysis can only determine the relation between quantities based on their dimension.  Dimensional analysis cannot give any insights into dimensionless quantities or their signs.

You can determine on dimensional grounds that the area $A$ of a circle of radius $r$ must be $A=k r^2$ where $k$ is a dimensionless constant, but you cannot obtain that $k=\pi$ on dimensional grounds alone.  Moreover, the actual sign of the proportionality constant is often a matter of convention; it may be that the sign can be obtain *on physical grounds* but never from dimensional analysis.